# List export to Excel

Tags: list-manipulation, export, excel

I want to export a nested list to Excel.
However when I try to do that every column in my list gets exported to a different sheet.
I used {} already in the Export statement to combine all colums and have them on one excel sheet. However then my format gets messed up.

When I use Flatten to remove the extra brackets the dates and vales are shown correctly but all data is in one column.

What I would like it to look like is:

[image]

How can I fix this?

My input is:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: you need to show an example of what your original data looks like and what you want it to look like in excel.

Comment: Give us `ExportList` in formatted so that we can copy it. You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  It is recommended that you browse [the Markdown help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site).

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure that's not the most efficient way, but to get you started...

First I simulate your data:

```
data = {{{{2016, 4, 1}, 100}, {{2016, 4, 4}, 200}}, {{{2016, 4, 1}, 
     300}, {{2016, 4, 5}, 400}}};
data // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Then after proper flattening etc:

```
exp = Flatten[{DateObject@#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ #] & /@ Transpose@data
(* {{DateObject[{2016, 4, 1}], 100, DateObject[{2016, 4, 1}], 
  300}, {DateObject[{2016, 4, 4}], 200, DateObject[{2016, 4, 5}], 
  400}} *)
Export["somefile.xlsx", exp]
```

or you can use `Apply` instead of one `Map`

```
exp = Flatten /@ Apply[{DateObject@#1, #2} &, Transpose@data, {2}]
```